# HTTPS over private network

Tags: ssl

My web server runs over a LAN(that means, I don't have a public IP address(domain name) to give to a Certificate Authority to get SSL work for me). My IP is a private one(10.100.10.239), but the service is provided through the ISP(my LAN is connected to the ISP by some means which I don't know) to my branch customers.  So, is it possible to implement SSL on my web server?(a web server with a private IP address) If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: You can implement SSL, but if you can't get a Certificate, your visitors will be warned by their browsers about to trust your own SSL Cert. The best way to solve that doubt is to phone your ISP support and ask them. They will know if is possible to redirect 443 connections to your private IP.

Answer (score 2):

As Darth mentioned, SSL certs rely on FQDN's (Fully Qualified Domain Names) not IP addresses.

So the question becomes, are you implementing internal DNS for this server such that whatever its hostname is resolves in your domain? For example, if your domain is example.com and your web server is called web, if you do a DNS lookup for web.example.com does it resolve? And to be clear, as you are stating that this is all on a private and not public facing network, you will want to check for those DNS records internally, not externally (use nslookup from a Win machine, or dig from a *nix machine).

Assuming you are using DNS records internally, then you could generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) from your web server for the FQDN web.example.com. You provide this CSR to the Certificate Authority of your choice, and they will generate the SSL certificate that you will then install into your web server.

Alternatively, depending on 'if' there are greater internal certificate needs, you could create your own CA and issue your own certs. There would be an extra step of needing to publish your CA certs to the browsers of all your internal computers so that they recognize the issuer of the SSL certs and not receive the cert warnings. This would be a lot more work and really only worthwhile if you will be utilizing the CA infrastructure for other needs.

Last but not least as Santeador mentioned you could just create a self-signed cert from the server itself and your users will simply have to trust the cert. The downside to self-signed certs is that there is no certificate chain to be able to verify their issuance, so it all depends on how secure you would like to be.

Addition: 
Timing is everything. Was doing some reading and landed across this that could help you if you would like to go the Self-Signed route (assuming that you are on Linux running Apache and not running IIS:
http://www.tecmint.com/enable-ssl-for-apache-on-centos/

Comment: "the Certificate Authority of your choice" will probably reject the CSR unless the CA's domain validation means can reach the server.

Comment: This means there will need to be at the very minimum a set of public-facing DNS records with the same hostnames as those of the private network, and said hostnames will be published in Certificate Transparency.

Answer (score 0):

SSL Certificates do not care about IP addresses, just hostnames (domain names). Sign whatever hostname you own that they're using to access your webserver (assuming you do own said hostname)

Comment: Commercial CAs don't sign certificates for non-FQDN hostnames or for FQDNs referring to a host whose port 443 is not reachable from the Internet.

Comment: @DamianYerrick The commercial CA I use simply requires that you be able to access a code sent to one of the emails in the DN's WHOIS block (billing, technical, administrative). I don't even have to have any records set up, much less one pointing to a webserver. Many SSL certificates are used for non-HTTPS purposes, so I doubt most other CAs require you to be running an HTTPS server to get one.

Comment: Then perhaps ACME CAs such as Let's Encrypt are an exception to the rule. They need either a reachable web server or dynamic DNS.

Comment: @DamianYerrick Yes, they are definitely not the norm currently. They are akin to a very interesting experiment right now.